# How to mosaic/bend/curve image with curvature in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, gis

I have an image that represents the elevation of some area. But the drone that made it didn't necessarily go in a straight line(although image is always rectangular). I also have gps coordinates generated every 20cm of the way.

How can I "bend" this rectangular image (curve/mosaic) so that it represents the curved path that the drone actually went through? (in python)

I haven't managed to write any code as I have no idea what is the name of this "warping" of the image. Please find the attached image as a wanted end state, and normal horizontal letters as a start state.

[image]

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @randomir please see the edit, I have no idea what is the name of this or any relevant scipy/PIL functions that would make this possible

Comment: Is the image supposed to show that the drone went over two hills, or followed a bendy river.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Followed a bendy river :D

Comment: You say "an image" - is it a single continuous image or multiple frames?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The output is a lengthy (vertical) image. For the sake of simplicity we can say that one horizontal line of image is generated every 20cm of flight and it represents elevation beneath the drone. For each line we have heading (rotation of the drone in degrees).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better answer, but I guess you could use the remapping functions of openCV for that.

The process would look like that :

1. From your data, get your warping function. This will be a function that maps (x,y) pixel values from your input image I to (x,y) pixel values from your output image O
2. Compute the size needed in the output image to host your whole warped image, and create it
3. Create two maps, mapx and mapy, which will tell the pixel coordinates in I for every pixel in 0 (that's, in a sense, the inverse of your warping function)
4. Apply OpenCV remap function (which is better than simply applying your maps because it interpolates if the output image is larger than the input)

Depending on your warping function, it might be very simple, or close to impossible to apply this technique.

You can find an example with a super simple warping function here : https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html

More complex examples can be looked at in OpenCV doc and code when looking at distortion and rectification of camera images.